# How to replace schema in SpringDocUtils only for one endpoint

Tags: spring, swagger, openapi

I had a problem in my open api page that showed LocalTime as

```json
"time": {
    "hour": 0,
    "minute": 0,
    "second": 0,
    "nano": 0
  }
```

By using the following block of code it is solved:

```kotlin
init {
        val schema: Schema<LocalTime> = Schema<LocalTime>()
        schema.example(LocalTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm")))
        SpringDocUtils.getConfig().replaceWithSchema(LocalTime::class.java, schema)
    }
```

But this also means for all LocalTime fields this new schema is implied. Since in some of the endpoints I may want to have seconds in formatting, how can I limit this to one endpoint.
p.s. I tried to create a separate schema class and use implementation option of @Schema annotation but the formatting was never applied. So any working example of this approach is appreciated.